# strftime is not recognizing american format in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime-format, strftime

I have a date coming in this format "MM-DD-YYY" from view and i want to save it in datetime format. 
I'm trying to convert to datetime format  using `strftime` but it is recognizing the date in "DD-MM-YYYY" format and therefore whenever my date exceeds 12 my code breaks.Please help.

After debugging i found another issue,the date is not coming when the date exceeds 12,which means if the date is not in "DD-MM-YYYY"fomat, it is not shown in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse a string with a specified formatting using [DateTime.strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime):

```
str = '12-31-1999' # intended to mean "December 31st, 1999"
parsed = DateTime.strptime(str, '%m-%d-%Y')
parsed.month
# => 12
```

Comment: Actually the problem is that the date is not coming to controller if it exceeds 12.

Comment: @SachinPrasad: it's hard to tell why that happens without seeing the code.